# App crashes when trying to access bluetooth devices

Tags: swift, macos, bluetooth

I'm trying to create an app to manage bluetooth devices on macOS. I have checked the "Bluetooth" box in "Signing & Capabilities" and I have created a Info.plist with the following content

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription</key>
    <string>App is managing bluetooth devices while sleeping</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

But when I launch the app in Xcode I still get the error:

> This app has crashed because it attempted to access privacy-sensitive data without a usage description.  The app's Info.plist must contain an NSBluetoothAlwaysUsageDescription key with a string value explaining to the user how the app uses this data.

I'm using `IOBluetooth` to get the list of paired devices and so far I haven't gotten farther than just trying to list the devices.

```swift
import SwiftUI
import IOBluetooth

struct BluetoothDevice: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    let name: String
    let connected: Bool
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let devices = IOBluetoothDevice.pairedDevices().filter { $0 is IOBluetoothDevice }.map {
        let device = $0 as! IOBluetoothDevice
        let id = UUID(uuidString: device.addressString)
        return BluetoothDevice(id: id ?? UUID(), name: device.name, connected: device.isConnected())
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            List(devices) {
                let connectedString = $0.connected ? "Connected" : "Disconnected"
                Text("\($0.name) \($0.id.uuidString) \(connectedString)")
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

#Preview {
    ContentView()
}
```

I'm new to macOS app development and Swift but everything looks correct to me and a lot of search results and also according to a certain (not so) intelligent AI.

Comment: In Xcode, select your app target and go to the Info tab. Add the Bluetooth privacy setting there. Don't manually edit a Info.plist.

Comment: Thanks that worked even after deleting the Info.plist file. Apparently I only found outdated information.

Comment: I expect your app wasn't actually bundling that Info.plist file. (Info.plist includes a lot of keys other than this one. It looks like you created a separate file and just gave it the same name.) Letting Xcode do the work will help avoid those kinds of problems.